# dart / flutter run process with sudo

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I would like to develop a flutter app for mac desktop and access the macs powermetrics with `sudo powermetrics` is there a way to ask the user for sudo privileges for this command on first run?

Answer (score 5):

Hi I am just playing with flutter and I was solving same question.

In general we need GUI version of sudo called from bash.

**example of bash commnad to run dscacheutil which needs sudo:**

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "dscacheutil -flushcache  2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
```

Then I was trying to run this command via Process.run() in flutter but no success. Then I created testing bash script and I tried to run bash script directly using Process.run(). It told me then I don't have privileges.

So I had to change my App Sandbox value to NO in Xcode.
We have to open `Runner.xcodeproj` directly inside `macos` folder.

[image]

**Then change App Sandbox to NO:**

[image]

**No we have to prepare our bash script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "dscacheutil -flushcache  2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
```

**Save it somewhere and last step we can call this bash script in flutter.**

```
void main() {

      Process.run('/Users/nikix/Desktop/bash_test.sh',[]).then((result){
      stdout.write(result.stdout);
      stderr.write(result.stderr);
      });
}
```

Now I am getting GUI prompt with sudo, it seems to work. But I really don't know if this is correct way. I am pretty new in flutter.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to build flutter app `flutter build macos` but bash script can't be run. Then I found [this package called process_run](https://pub.dev/packages/process_run)

Then I was able to run custom bash script from builded app

**In your yaml pubspec.yaml add that package:**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  process_run: any
```

**Next step is to allow Sanbox App for release version of app in xcode:**

[image]

**Last step run our bash code in Dart:**

```
import 'package:process_run/shell.dart';
void main() {

  var shell = Shell();

  shell.run("""
    #!/bin/bash
    /usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script "dscacheutil -flushcache  2>&1 etc" with administrator privileges'
    """).then((result){
      print('Shell script done!');
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('Shell.run error!');
      print(onError);
    });
};
```

Comment: Best information from all over the internet. This should be accepted as answer.

Comment: @Saikathalder - Thank you! I am glad it is still valid. I don't work with flutter for some time now. Have a great day!

Comment: by any chance do you know how do I run a executable with this? 
For example: run as simple as 'rclone --version' ? I have copied executables and tried this, which work in debug mode. But when I build macos, it does not work anymore.